# Idiom for global shortcuts on mobile devices

Tags: mobile, mobile-application, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a mobile web app and there are two different modes for viewing content and the user may frequently toggle between them. I'd like to provide a very convenient way for the user to request this toggle action.

A link onscreen isn't good, because the content is full screen and so the link would block it. Gestures might be okay, but might also interfere with what each view wants to do with a gesture.

What I'd really like is the mobile equivalent of a global hotkey, something that you can do that would be handled by the app and then relayed to the content pane if not handled globally.

Is there a good way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

Many mobile devices have operating systems that allow them to program either soft or hard keys that can be used to perform certain functions (e.g. take screen shots by pressing a combination of keys), so that's certainly one solution that you can think about.

The trouble with implementing global shortcuts is that they might interfere with existing shortcuts that have been assigned, or that the user will move between devices and also become a bit confused because of how the shortcuts will or won't work on different devices.